# What type of data is available at the "census block" level?

Tags: data, census, united-states

I'm curious what is available at the 'Census Block' level,  the finest scale.  I found this dataset:  http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2010/TABBLOCK/2010/

It contains HOUSING10 and POP10,  but I would like to get Vacant vs. Occupied Housing and income if possible.

In spite of the fact that it says this is answered elsewhere, it is not.   Only # of houses and total population are addressed in the other post.   The question here is...  What addtional attributes are available at the 'census block' level?  How do you obtain these additional attributes?

Comment: @erica, whuber: I'd like this reopened, please. I was about to post a generic answer to the Q "what type of data is available at census block level" in *any* country. Often this means "why is my-desired-detail-data not available at census block level?" The "already answered" Q is on *sourcing* the data, a different issue.

Comment: @whuber, erica - I suppose i could always ask then answer my own Q. :-)

Comment: @martin Have you considered posting such an answer in the duplicate thread? Alternatively, you can indeed ask and answer your own question. (I would love to see you effectively answer dozens of similar questions at once in that fashion.) But re-opening an obvious duplicate, even to accomplish such a laudable goal, doesn't seem like a great way get your information out there.

Comment: The links to the 'already answered' question are dead or do not contain the information I am looking for.   I can and have found population and # of houses at the census block level,  but can not find tables that contain any other information at the census block level.   I've followed the advice here and at the duplicate question, as well as several other sites similar to this one, to no avail.

Comment: How about rewording to something like "why is there no other info than ... at the census level"?

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, it asks about something different. Not only that, but after examining the posting **Where to get 2010 Census Block data**, I can say that none of the answers offered aid in answering Jim Richards' question. Please re-examine the assessment of this being a duplicate question, because it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Use [American Fact Finder](http://factfinder2.census.gov). If you use the "Guided Search" it walks you through finding the particular data you want -- for example, "Occupancy and Vacancy Status" in Step 2, then pick what block groups you need the information for in Step 3.

Often such detail data isn't provided in shapefiles, but you can join it to census block polygons to work with in your GIS.

Comment: I used the above method an dI was able to produce a table, but it didn't contain the needed Geoid or 'census block' key to join it to a spatial database.Total:      Occupied Vacant
Block Group 1, Census Tract 100, Alpine County,California  917  236 681

Comment: @JimRichalds Is there a FIPS code field?

Comment: No,  I must be doing something wrong.   I produced a clunky downloadable table no FIPS code.